# NSUserDefaults Automatic Loading and Saving Data

Tags: objective-c, load, save, nsuserdefaults

What I'm trying to figure out is how to automatically save and load data using NSUserDefaults. I know how to do save and load data if I have save and load button, using NSUserDefault. I'm not sure which of the methods I should be using in the AppDelegate, if that is right?

Can somebody point me help me, please?

Thanks

Sam x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on when (at which point in the lifecycle of the application) you want the loading and saving to happen. The earliest point for loading though I think is when applicationDidFinishLaunching is called.

Comment: I'm looking to save the data whenever the user exits the app to go to the home screen and quits the app. Loading the data is when the app first loads back into memory.

When I mean quit, I mean when you double tab the home button and scroll along to the app and either swipe it up or press the little 'x'

I'll have a look at 'applicationDidFinishLaunching', but the saving part still puzzles me?

Comment: To perform some action when the application is being terminated you should implement in your application delegate a method: - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Thanks, Rudi for your help. I'll go away and have a play.